# How can I prove that $4^n-1$ is divisible by 3?

Tags: number-theory, induction

I was faced with the hypothesis that $4^n-1$ is always divisible by 3. I *believe* that this problem can be solved by a proof by induction.

As far as I understand, a proof by induction works by first testing whether or not this is true for a small value of n (e.g. 0, 1, etc.). Then we assume that it is true for an arbitrary number $n=k$, and prove how it is also true for $n=k+1$.

#### My first step

At first, I tried to prove it for a small number ($n=1$).

$$4^1-1 = 3$$

3 is clearly divisible by 3, so the first step should hold true. However, I am completely stuck now when trying to prove that the same holds true for $4^{k}-1$ and $4^{k+1}-1$.

Comment: You should assume $4^k-1$ is divisible by $3$ and show $4^{k+1}-1=4^{k+1}-4^k+4^k-1$ is divisible by $3$

Comment: However, if you want to do it by induction, note $4^{k+1}-1=4(4^k-1)+3$

Comment: The easiest proof without induction is probably based on multiplying out $(3+1)^n$. It is easy to see that every summand apart from the final $1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry, I don't quite follow how you got to that conclusion.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242646/simple-proof-show-that-4n-1-is-divisible-by-3-guided-proof-task

Comment: using binomial expansion, $(3+1)^n=3^n+n3^{n-1}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}23^{n-2}+\cdots+1$

Comment: " Then we ***assume that it is true for an arbitrary number n=k***, and prove how it is also true for n=k+1".  "However, I am completely stuck now when trying *to prove that the same holds true for $4^k−1$* and $4^{k+1}−1$"  You *don't* prove it for $4^k-1$.  You ***assume it is true*** for $4^k-1$.  So we *ASSUME* there is an $m$ so that $4^k -1 = 3m$.  $4^k = 3m +1$.  SO $4^{k+1} = 4\cdot4^{k}= 4(3m +1)=12m + 4$. so $4^{k+1} - 1 = 12m + 3 = 3(4m + 1)$.  So if we *ASSUME* $3|4^k -1$  we *proved* that $4^{k+1} -1$ is *also* divisible by $3$ ***assuming*** $4^k-1$ was in the first place.

Comment: What peter is getting at is that if you have $(a+b)^n$ you get $a^n + na^{n-1}b + .... bunch\ of\ terms ... + nab^{n-1} + b^n= a^n + b^n + $ a bunch of terms that all have factors of $ab$ in them.   So $4^n = (3 + 1)^n = 3^n + n3^{n-1} + .... $ a bunch of terms that are multiples of powers of $3 ....  + n3^2 \color{red}{+1}$.  As $3^n + n3^{n-1} + .... $ a bunch of terms that are multiples of powers of $3$ is $\color{green}{\text{a multiple of 3}}$ you know that $4^n= \color{green}{\text{a multiple of 3}}\color{red}{+1}$.  So $4^n\color{red}{-1}=\color{green}{\text{a multiple of 3}}$

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$4^{n}-1 = (4-1)(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+\dots + 4 + 1) = 3(4^{n-1}+4^{n-2}+\dots + 4 + 1)$$

Which is clearly $\boxed{\text{divisible by }3.}$

Or, a proof by induction:

Note that $4^{1}-1 = 3$. Now, assume that the statement is true for $n=k$. Then, we have:

$$4^{k+1}-1 = 4(4^{k}-1)+3$$

However, the RHS is a multiple of $3$ plus $3$, so it must be divisible by $3$. Thus, the statement is true for $n = k+1$ if it is true for $n=k$, completing the proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $4^{k+1}-1=4\cdot 4^k-1=3\cdot 4^k+(4^k-1)$.

Comment: This is a rather huge hint if I do say so myself.

Comment: Forgive my lack of mathemathical ability, but how exactly is $4*4^k-1$ equal to $3*4^k+(4^k-1)$?

Comment: Because $4\cdot 4^k=(3+1)\cdot 4^k=3\cdot 4^k+4^k$.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. It hasn't really *clicked* yet, but I'll go through it with a pen and paper in a second and see if I can get to the solution. I'm not sure if it was a bad or silly question to ask, because it got downvoted and closed, but I don't know how to read the notation in the other question, so it's not that helpful to me.

Comment: View it this way.  $4^{k+1} + 1 = 4\cdot 4^k -1 = (3 + 1)4^k - 1 = (3\cdot 4^k + 4^k) - 1 =3\cdot 4^k + (4^k - 1)$.   .... Alternatively assume $4^k - 1 = 3M$ then $4(4^k -1) = 4\cdot 3M = 12M$.  So $4^{k+1} -4 = 12 M$ and $4^{k+1} - 4 + 3 = 12 M + 3$ and $4^{k+1} - 1 = 3(4M + 1)$.... !or! ..... $4^k -1 = 3M$ so $4^k = 3M+1$ so $4^{k+1} = 12M +4$ so $4^{k+1} -1 = 12M + 3=3(4M+1)$.

Comment: @fleablood Completely understand the steps until $3*4^k + (4^k-1)$. Does that already prove that it's divisible by 3? I know $3*4^k$ is divisible by 3. Ah, and I *assumed* that $4^k-1$ was divisible by 3, so I have two expressions that are divisible by 3, added together. And $3*x + 3*y = 3(x+y)$, which is also divisible by 3. So both expressions are divisible by 3, therefore, the entire expression must be divisible by 3. Did I get that right?

Comment: That's a proof by induction.  You *show* what you want to prove for *one* case.  You show that if you have a case (perhaps we shouldn't say you "assume" it; maybe we should say ***IF*** you have it for a case) it follows that you will have it for the next case.  And that's the end of your proof. You showed it was true for the first case, you showed if it's true for any case it's true for the next.  So it is true for the first, the second, the next, and the next for ever. ... so if we *know* $4^k-1$ is a multiple of $3$ then we *know* $3\cdot 4^k + (4^k-1)$ will also be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you. I believe I understand now. I have to admit last time I did mathemathical proofs was already a few years ago, so it what may be blantantly obvious to a lot of people here is not that obvious to me. Thank you very much still for taking the time to explain it to me and help me become a tiny bit less stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

As $$4 \equiv 1 [3]$$ you get by induction $$4^n \equiv 1 [3]$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and therefore the desired result.